# EJB 3.0 Interface class extending Serializable throwing cannot marshal EJB parameters

Tags: serialization, interface, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

One of my POJO class is implementing an interface which extends Serializable

My doubt is, As we cant include serialVersionUID in interface class can it result in Cannot Marshal EJB parameters Exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass ,,an interface" as parameter of java method. You can only pass an instance of some class, that implements such interface. That class will be marked as `Serializable` due to abstraction hierarchy.  The `Serializable` interface is a marker interface, and your implementation class will be serializable even if it does not declare the serialVersionUid attribute(However, it is strongly recommended that you do declare the serialVersionUID).
So to answer your question: as long as the particular instance you pass to your EJB method is marked as serializable it will be fine.